# Computation time of processor varies on execution, each time by using gettimeofday() in a C program

Tags: c, linux, time, gettimeofday

I am trying to compare the `computation time` for performance comparison using different C libraries with `gettimeofday()` by including `time.h` and `sys/time.h` header files.

I used `gettimeofday()` at the start and end of my computation and took the difference. But each time I execute my C code, I get fluctuating time as answer. For example

```
0.007 sec,
0.004 sec,
0.009 sec etc.
```

Is there a way I could take the average of 50 such results other than manually make 50 such executions and taking the average of all results.

Comment: On what operating system? `gettimeofday` suggests some POSIX one, perhaps Linux...

Comment: Not really. Put the code in a loop, calculate the total for each call inside the loop, and then show the average. And note that 50 iterations is usually to little, try doing it at least a few thousand times. And with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Operating system is Linux.

Comment: @Ema: then you need to edit your question to improve it, at least by tagging it better

Comment: @Ema You are measuring too small units of work. Your operating system has a lot of things to do, (flush written data to disk, handle network packets, handle timekeeping, handle memory allocation etc.)  and there are a lot of processes running that does various taks.. Fluctuations like you see in the handful of miliseconds range is perfectly normal. So what you need to do is to time your computation perhaps 1000 times. (e.g. by running the the computation in a loop of 1000, or run your entire program 1000 times,  and divide by 1000 to get an average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But each time I execute my C code, I get fluctuating time as answer.

This fluctuation is unrelated to C or to `gettimeofday`. Current processors and operating systems make such execution time fluctuate (e.g. because [cache misses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) or [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) may be non-deterministic, and because [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), [preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)), [page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault), [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) etc... happen at any time).

In practice, read carefully [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) (maybe you also want to use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) and/or [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) and/or [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html)...). Set-up your benchmark to last at least one second (so repeat your benchmarked functions many times). Run several benchmarks and several times the same benchmark.